# Could you explain this construction?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, passive-voice

What is the construction *be* + verb (perfect form)? I have come across it multiple times in legalese. For instance:

> **to** ensure that every person **be granted** adequate assistance

Comment: It has nothing to do with the _to_; that's there to introduce the infinitive _ensure_. It's the _that_ you should be looking at. It introduces an object complement clause, which in this case is an untensed ("infinitive") construction -- _be granted_ instead of _is granted_. The _be granted_ construction itself is simply a passive, but it's a passive promoting the indirect object _every person_ to subject, instead of the direct object _adequate assistance_. LIke the difference between _The book was given (to) her_ and _She was given the book_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"be" in "be granted" in your sentence is present tense subjunctive of the verb to be.

In English this subjunctive form looks like an infinitive and that's why it is often seen as an infinitive.

Only if you have a look at other languages you see that the subjunctive forms are different from indicative forms:

Latin est x sit*

German ist x sei*

French est x soit*

English is x be*

Unfortunately in English the subjunctive form and the infinitive have got the same form in the course of centuries, so that a real feeling for the subjunctive form be* is hardly possible.

This present subjunctive is usual in American English after verbs such as to demand:

- They demanded that each of them be* given an equal share.

For more information you have to use a grammar.